# SSRS report - controllers/edit the layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, reporting-services, controls

I am a beginner in programming, and would like to ask for some help.

I am currently working on a project which uses an SSRS report to display a table on my webpage. The problem with it, is that it is too big for the page, and you have to scroll along the horizontal axis to view all columns.

I was wondering, is there a way to control the size of the SSRS report - it is currently using the tag: rsweb:ReportViewer - I am also using Twitter Bootstrap - I just want to add the report in a container, and have the scrollbars appear in the container, so that they can view the whole report, without moving the actual page - I hope this makes sense.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The code in my .aspx page is:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptOutstandingSupplierReport" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"  Width="100%" Height="1000px" ZoomMode="PageWidth" AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="true">    
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code behind is:

```
private void OutstandingSupplierPayment(string sCompany)
{
    IReportServerCredentials irs = new CustomReportCredentials(" *removed credentials*" );
    ReportParameter[] rptParam = new ReportParameter[1];
    rptParam[0] = new ReportParameter();
    rptParam[0].Name = "CompanyID";
    rptParam[0].Values.Add(sCompany);

    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irs;
    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(Session["ReportServer"].ToString());
    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.ServerReport.ReportPath = "*removed path*";
    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParam);
    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;
    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.ServerReport.Refresh();
    rptOutstandingSupplierReport.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you

Comment: Better edit your question to add this information. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that - I was wondering if there was a better way to add code to my question - I have now added some code my question

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx page try using the server tag with zoom mode 
Create a hidden variable to set the Zoom percantage

```
  <input type="hidden" runat ="server" id="hdzoomper"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var height=   window.screen.availHeight;
     var width =   window.screen.availWidth;
     if(height > 1200 and  width >1000)document.getElementByID('hdzoomper').value = 100;
          else     if(height > 1000 and  width > 800)
       document.getElementByID('hdzoomper').value = 80;              



         <script>
          <% int ZoomPer = int.Parse(hdzoomper.Value);  %>

       <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group"> 
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptOutstandingSupplierReport" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"  Width="100%" Height="1000px" ZoomMode='<%=ZoomPer%>' AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="true">    
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

Comment: I added this to my code but I got a: 'Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ZoomMode' from its string representation '<%ZoomPer%>' for the 'ZoomMode' property' @rmehra76

Comment: add the reference of reporting libraries Microsoft.webform.reporting and others

Comment: Hi, I already have these references on the top of my programme - I still have not managed to get this to work - thanks for your input so far. @rmehra76

Comment: Another way is to create an Iframe in an HTML page          <iframe id="ReportFrame" height: 500px; visibility: hidden"></iframe>            and in that I frame pass the screen resolution in the querystring.  $("#ReportFrame").show();
      you can fire this on click or on load of window in jquery  $("#ReportFrame")
            .attr('src',
                "<yourpath>./Reports.aspx?resolution=document.getElementByID('hdzoomper').value)  In the page load event in aspx set the zoom size based on parameter resolution let me know if this does not work for you

Comment: Would you be able to use some of my code to show me the layout please? And also, i'm not entirely sure how to set the zoom size in the code behind - The reason I ask for this is that I have previously tried to put the SSRS report on an iframe but I got a server error. Thanks. @rmehra76

Comment: Yes , you can send your code segment .For changing the size play around with the following properties of your reportviewer      
 viewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(99); viewer.ZoomPercent = 80;(viewer is your ReportViewer object

Comment: My aspx code can be found in my original question. my code behind consists of connection strings, zoom mode :page width and the visible is set to true. There isn't anything else that could help with the layout. I would appreciate any help that you can provide. @rmehra76